# How to run SOQL query via jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, google-apps-script, soql

I've been following the guide here on making an apex rest call via ajax, but all I get is a status 0 error.
http://www.oyecode.com/2014/02/how-to-salesforce-rest-api-from-browser.html

Are there other guides/tutorials on how to make a SOQL query via ajax? What have I done incorrectly?

Here is what I currently have. It shouldn't make a difference, but I'm making this call from htmlservice using google apps script.

```
$.ajax(
{
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://na15.salesforce.com/services/data/v26.0/query/?q=SELECT+Name+FROM+Account+LIMIT+5",
  beforeSend: function (xhr) 
  {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer eeeee.xxxxxx");
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', "application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader('dataType', "jsonp");
    //usually not needed but when you are
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
  },
  success: function (data) 
  {
    alert(data);
  },
  error: function(one, two, three)
  {
    alert(one.status);
    alert(two);
    alert(three);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question but im using the following connector for a few years and it does the job like a charm:
https://github.com/gidzone/cloudconnector